LWM2M over MQTT
I'm trying to face the search for an implementation of an LWM2M server over MQTT broker.
I know there's a specification by ESR Consortium the LWM2m over MQTT.
I found a couple of implementations around the web the eclipse Leshan and a plugin of the EMQX the LwM2M Gateway.
My question is do other implementations exist or where can I start searching for other implementations?
